# Upgrade to Drupal 4.7.12 failed (while upgrading from 4.7.11 to 4.7.21)

Tags: drupal, upgrade

Trying to upgrade from 4.7.11 to 4.7.12 but failed.

Here is debug info:

```
[Error: Add Data Type column to civicrm_option_group]
Error Field Error Value
Type    DB_Error
Code    -19
Message DB Error: no such field
Mode    16

UserInfo:
    UPDATE `civicrm_option_group_en_US` SET `data_type` = 'Integer' WHERE name IN ('activity_type', 'gender', 'payment_instrument', 'participant_role', 'event_type') [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'data_type' in 'field list']

DebugInfo
    UPDATE `civicrm_option_group_en_US` SET `data_type` = 'Integer' WHERE name IN ('activity_type', 'gender', 'payment_instrument', 'participant_role', 'event_type') [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'data_type' in 'field list']
```

However, field `data_type` DOES exist.

Comment: You sure you mean 4.7.12 rather than the latest release which is 4.7.21

Comment: Yes, since updates were not done regularly, I was trying to make it from 4.7.10 to 4.7.21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to manually create `data_type` field in `log_civicrm_option_group` table.

```
ALTER TABLE `log_civicrm_option_group` ADD `data_type` VARCHAR(128) 
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci 
NULL DEFAULT NULL 
COMMENT 'Data Type of Option Group.';
```